# SQL Azure DB throws error 'login failed for user' during web app backup

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a sql azure web app with a connected database.  When I try to automate a daily backup of my web app including the database I get the following error:

> 'login failed for user ******'

The asp.net web app is connecting and getting data from the database without error.  This error only happens during the web app backup process.

I have checked the connection string in both the web app **PROPERTIES** and the **DATA CONNECTIONS** blades.

The connection strings are the same in both blades and look like:

> Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****;User ID=****;Password=****;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

If I open SSMS and use the server, password, and user from my connection string I can connect without any issue.

Also, when I got to the Blade for the database in question and click on the activity log, I get no entries and don't see any connection errors

Can someone help me figure out why my azure web app cannot backup the database during its backup operation

---

### EDIT 1:

The activity log linked to an error log file and this is what it contained

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:f85ceeef-0001-00de-1a27-6cbdab000000 Time:2017-01-11T16:26:09.4122657Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was rwdl 2017-01-08T16:16:47Z 2290-10-23T15:16:47Z /blob/******/$root 2015-04-05
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: paste the entire error

Comment: that is the entire error, it is found through looking at the activity log for the web service.  Is there another place I can go to get a more detailed error?

Comment: @TheGameiswar I found a link to a "log/error" file and added the contents to my post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate these kind of answers,

but after getting no help from microsoft **RANT BEGIN** [other than googling my question and returning stack exchange answers to me then suggesting I open a support ticket - which of course is a paid feature...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/72a6eb97-2663-4f14-a6ad-bf62a426680d/azure-backup-for-app-service-fails-with-login-failed-for-uer?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#2fdd5e7e-4479-4a44-9078-9fb078587a9a) **RANT END**

**SOLUTION**
My best guess is that there was an issue with the backup configuration because I deleted the existing backup configuration and recreated it with the same values and now it works.  Maybe I should have created the Blob container before rather than during the backup setup.  I don't know but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that Azure resources are whitelisted in your Azure SQL Server firewall settings?

Comment: When I open the firewall settings blade the "allow access to azure services" settings is marked as ON